# Build a RSS reader

Tags: android, rss

hi 
  i am developing a RSS reader for android.My application is showing no error or exception.
But it is not giving the desired output.
Only one message come on my emulator NO RSS feed available 
what could be the reason for it.

Comment: You probably have a bug.